# Data not printing correctly on PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, xhtml, itext

Here's my XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<META content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="Center"
    style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word; width: 97%"
    bordercolor="4f81BD" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="color: white;">
            <td height="31" bgcolor="#4f81BD"
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none; border-Right: none; border-top: none; border-width: 1px"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">Type</span></td>
            <td bgcolor="#4f81BD"
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none; border-Right: none; border-top: none; border-width: 1px"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">Custodian
            Name</span></td>
            <td bgcolor="#4f81BD"
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none; border-Right: none; border-top: none; border-width: 1px"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">Relationship
            to Owner</span></td>
            <td bgcolor="#4f81BD"
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none; border-Right: none; border-top: none; border-width: 1px"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">Percent</span></td>
            <td bgcolor="#4f81BD"
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none; border-Right: none; border-top: none; border-width: 1px"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">Minor
            Name</span></td>
            <td bgcolor="#4f81BD"
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none; border-Right: none; border-top: none; border-width: 1px"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">For the
            State of</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family: SansSerif;" align="center">
            <td
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: solid; border-top: none; border-Right: none; border-width: 1px;"
                align="Center"><span style="font-weight: Bold">
            UTMA/UGMA</span></td>
            <td
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: solid; border-top: none; border-Right: none; border-width: 1px;"
                align="Center"><span>QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
            MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM</span></td>
            <td
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: solid; border-top: none; border-Right: none; border-width: 1px;"
                align="Center"><span>Common Law Husband</span></td>
            <td
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: solid; border-top: none; border-Right: none; border-width: 1px;"
                align="Center"><span>15%</span></td>
            <td
                style="border-left: solid; border-bottom: solid; border-top: none; border-Right: solid; border-width: 1px;"
                align="Center">RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</td>
            <td
                style="border-left: none; border-bottom: solid; border-top: none; border-Right: none; border-width: 1px;"
                align="Center"><span>DC</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to convert it into a PDF with this code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
    import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;

    public class Practice {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws 
IOException, DocumentException {
            String inputFile = "sample.xhtml";
            String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
            String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(url);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os);

            os.close();
        }
    }
```

It's giving me this output:

[image]

But when I open the XHTML in a browser, it's like this:

[image]

I am not getting the problem. My main aim is to break the words in that given space. I use iText 2.0.8 and I can't use other APIs as my company does not allow that. Any suggestion would be a lot of help.

Comment: Guessing here: maybe iText doesn't understand CSS properties `table-layout` or `word-wrap`? I'd try removing those first. Also, try removing your `<td>` styles and moving them to a stylesheet.

Comment: Also, if you want a quick solution, you could get something up and running with `wkhtmltopdf`, and then come back to an iText solution once that's live.

Comment: Its recognizing table-layout, not word-wrap. If I dont use word-wrap, how can I break the words?

Comment: I can't use anything other than iText.

Comment: Won't the words wrap automatically without that CSS property? Try it! Also, if you explain _why_ you can't use anything other than iText, that context may be useful to your readers. Server limitation? Corporate directive? etc.

Comment: No they won't. So I added word-wrap. Yes, corporate directive. So cant use anything other than iText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a version of iText that's several years old. Why don't you use a current version and see whether the problem has been taken care of? They've done a huge amount of work converting HTML and XML to PDF (and vice versa) during this time. In fact, I'd say, it's been the principal thing they've worked on.

Comment: Agreed. But what would be the potential impacts if I change the version? My whole project is working based on 2.0.8

Comment: @sans481: Is your problems resolved with new version ? I am using 2.1.7 and facing word wrap issue. Any pointers will be really helpful

Comment: @HardikMishra: No, I did not fix it. But through the forums, I got to know that its due to old version of iText.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Flying Saucer (org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer), a library that converts XHTML+CSS to PDF.  It uses iText for the PDF generation.

If your problem is in the CSS support you should be looking at Flying Saucer.  The XHTML and CSS rendering is done before iText is used to convert the rendered content to PDF.