# Unexpected Wrapping on Special Characters In Flying Saucer / IText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I have a java application that generates PDF through the workflow: **Java -> XML + XSL -> HTML -> Flying Saucer -> PDF**. I am using the following maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

At a point in my report I need to display the name "Employee age (numeric value)" in a smallish column. In the HTML it looks correct throughout the resizing process, in the smallest size we can see that the wrapping does not break up any of the words, it only wraps on white space.

[image]

I take the HTML and run it through the following bit of FlyingSaucer / Itext code.

```
File pdf = new File(creationDir, fileName + "." + uuid + ".pdf");
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
sharedContext.setPrint(true);
sharedContext.setInteractive(false);
sharedContext.setReplacedElementFactory(new Base64ImgReplacedElementFactory());
sharedContext.getTextRenderer().setSmoothingThreshold(0);
renderer.setDocument(html);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream(pdf, true));
return pdf;
```

When I look at the text in the produced PDF I see this:
[image]

This seems to be incorrect as the "(" should be on the second line in front of "numeric". As far as I can tell it seems a whitespace may be added automatically at the end of special characters? If I replace the "(" with any alphanumeric character it is wrapped correctly as part of the word on the second line. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of iText are you using? See, f.e., https://stackoverflow.com/q/11429964/2564301

Comment: The itextpdf dependency is version 5.3.0

Comment: Can you reproduce this with iText 5.5.13?

Comment: I have explicitly pulled in the com.itextpdf itextpdf maven dependency version 5.5.13 and it has made no difference.

Comment: However, you made me think about checking new versions of the flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 dependency and it seemed I was out of date and changing that to the latest fixed the issue